Help needed fixing a corrupted sound subsystem on Ubuntu 24.04
While installing some different packages in an attempt to access some advanced features on my sound card, I have messed up a properly working sound system on my Ubuntu 24.04 computer.
The symptom is the dreaded "Dummy Output" listed for the Output Device in Settings, with no other sound cards available.
jhuber@t5610:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:277: no soundcards found...

jhuber@t5610:~$ inxi -A
Audio:
Device-1: Intel C600/X79 series High Definition Audio driver: N/A
Device-2: NVIDIA GK106 HDMI Audio driver: N/A
Device-3: Conexant Systems CX23885 PCI Video and Audio Decoder
  driver: cx23885
Device-4: C-Media CMI8738/CMI8768 PCI Audio driver: N/A
API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-51-generic status: kernel-api
Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active

So, the sound devices are recognized, but it seems that the drivers are not getting installed.  I have tried numerous fixes suggested by various web pages, to no avail.  The suggestions have included removing/purging/reinstalling alsa, pipewire, ubuntu-desktop, stopping/restarting various sound components with systemctl, and other things as well.
I think the package that broke things was installing oss4-gtk, which promised that it could access some additional SPDIF input settings on the CMI8768.  I was having difficulty capturing an SPDIF input stream.  I think the CMI8768 is sampling at 96 kHz, but the software only has settings up to 48 kHz, as I am taking in twice as much data as I should be.  In Windows, one can control the sampling rate of the card with the driver, so I was looking for a way to do that in Ubuntu.
But now, I would just like to get basic sound back.  I have removed all the additional packages I installed today, but that hasn't solved the problem.  It seems like I need to trigger some kind of rebuilding of the sound system.  Or perhaps there is a configuration file somewhere that needs to be deleted and rebuilt.  I ran into a similar issue a number of years ago with 16.04; I deleted a configuration file somewhere and the sound system was rebuilt, but I don't remember what I did.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
UPDATE: issuing the following commands brings the soundcards back!  Somehow I have wiped out the mechanism that loads them on startup.
jhuber@t5610:~$ sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
jhuber@t5610:~$ sudo modprobe snd_cmipci


So, I was able to solve the problem.  It seems that sudo apt-get remove did fully remove the oss4 packages from the computer.  Using sudo dpkg -P oss4-base removed a number of other files (mostly from /etc), and that fixed the problem.
